# Possible to take into account previous review/flagging history?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, review-badges

I've been reviewing posts on Stack Overflow since before the new [*Reviewer*](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer) badge and stat tracker was brought in.

I assume it isn't possible to retrospectively update the review stats as the necessary code didn't exist at the time? Unless it is a bug, in which case it would be great if the stats could just be updated.

If not, I understand the difficulty in working out the exact number of previously *reviewed* posts, but is it possible to take into account something like flag history?

For example: I have flagged over 100 posts through the review process, which would already be past half way to the 200 *actioned* mark necessary to attain the badge.

Comment: As you mentioned, I don't think the data exists to do that.